# Implementing a function in C++ which prints arguments in a space separated manner

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to implement a function `myprint` in C++ which takes a variable number of arguments - of any arbitrary type (could be int, double or string) - and print them separated with spaces, ending with a newline. For example both the following instances of the function call should work:

```
myprint(a,b,c)
```

and

```
myprint(a,b,c,d)
```

where a,b,c,d can be of any arbitrary type (out of those previously mentioned). I would prefer if `myprint` internally used `cout` for printing instead of `printf`. It is acceptable for the function to be a macro function instead of a variadic function. I've tried both approaches but haven't been successful so far. Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

The purpose of me wanting to implementing such a function is to replace lengthy and hard-to-type `cout` statements while debugging a code with a simple function call, saving time and improving readability in the process.

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried.

Comment: This can be easily done with a variadic template.

Comment: I had just begun reading about variadic functions to implement this, but they seem to require the number of variables to be printed, and their respective types beforehand (such a function is quite easy to implement). Part of the objective of asking this question is to determine whether or not something like this is even possible. I'm not looking for a complete implementation, but just a nudge in the right direction as to how I should go about implementing this.

Comment: With variadic functions you cannot determine the number of arguments and their type. You must provide this information in some way. The method use by the `printf` family of functions is one possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple using variadic templates.

```
template <typename Head>
void myprint(Head&& h) {
    std::cout << h << std::endl;
}

template <typename Head, typename... Tail>
void myprint(Head&& h, Tail&&... t) {
    std::cout << h << " ";
    myprint(std::forward<Tail&&>(t)...);
}
```

Use like this:

```
myprint(1, "Hello", 3.5, 0);
```

There has to be an overload of `<<` for all types passed to `myprint` though.

See [live example](http://ideone.com/dcCrwQ)

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I required. I was unaware of the existence of variadic templates in C++ before this, else I wouldn't have posted the question. Thanks again.